# Word count and display program

Tags: php

How do I count the total words in a paragraph?

If the paragraph contains fifteen words or more the program should display the fifteen words and add read more to the end of the fifteen words. The program must be written with PHP.

what I have so far is the code to add the read more text:

function new_excerpt_more($more){
global $post;

return '
ID).'">Read More
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_morre');

however, I am confused as to how to excerpt the blog post. Can anyone hep me?

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet? This isn't a homework helper site.

Comment: Take a look at `if`, `str_word_count`, and `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$parag  = 'This is a paragraph'; 
echo str_word_count($parag);
```

Comment: No, that doesn't do what the OP is asking for.

Comment: No that doesn't do what i am asking for. That just display the total words in the string. I am asking about how to excerpt a blog text instead of displaying the full text...and at the end of the excerpt text a "read more" link should be added

Comment: My bad. You can write a scraper that scraps the blog and perform some slicing operations tho.

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to allow you to count the amount of text to be output and then append the read more button at the end:

wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 20, 'Read More')